# Redirect to another page after button submit

Tags: php, redirect

I am building an application where details are displayed (admin.php).The user clicks on edit(edit.php) and he is redirected to another page to edit his details. Once the edit is done the values are updated and I want to redirect to the previous page once again where the details are displayed. All the operations carry out as desired , but when I try to redirect inside the "submit" to the previous page it doesn't occur.

Admin.php

```
    $event_id = $_SESSION['fedit'];
    if($_GET['edit'])
    {
     $url = "edit.php?event_id=". $event_id;  
     header("Location: $url");
    }
```

Edit.php

```
     if($_GET["Submit"])
              {
                 $val=$_GET['event'];
                 $remail=$_GET['email'];
                $rname = $_GET['ename'];
                $sqt=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET NAME='$rname',EMAIL='$remail' WHERE EID ='$val'");
                $page= "admin.php";
                header("Location: $page");
             }
```

Comment: see the errors or warnings in the log file. Maybe you got "headers already sent" message

Comment: What certainly "doesn't occur"? What do you see on the screen?

Comment: I get to see the same form.. as in just the table without values and the submit button

Comment: just try add die(); after header call

Comment: @DevMetal91 I got it right after using js for redirection.. thnx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you have placed this code on the page but if somehow a http header output is being sent before that **header(location:"")** then it wont work. Try the suggestions by other people, but if all else fails, you might wanna use JS.

```
echo "<script>window.location.assign("admin.php")</script>";
```

Use that instead of

```
header("Location: $page");
```

and it should work I guess.

Comment: +1, its very helpful... i was trying since a long and tried a lot, but this only works. thnx mishra boss

Answer (score 0):

add `action='edit.php' method='get'` to your form tag.
and in edit.php page place your rest of the code after submit.

Comment: as u said its not working within 'if($_GET["Submit"]){}', set a flag in there and then outside that if statement check the flag value exists or not. try to redirect from there.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably do this:

```
if ($_GET["Submit"]) {
   ...

   // Clean any output
   ob_clean();
   header("Location: $page");

   // Exit the PHP process 
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell what are you doing from the incomplete code you posted.
However, it looks like that not redirect but form submission is broken.
There are also 2 serious flaws in your code:

- Whatever edits have to be done using POST method, not GET
- you have to properly format your SQL query.

Anyway, here is an example of such an application (though editing only one field. you can easily add more) which works.

```
<?  
mysql_connect(); 
mysql_select_db("new"); 
$table = "test"; 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { //form handler part: 
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
  if ($id = intval($_POST['id'])) { 
    $query="UPDATE $table SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id"; 
  } else { 
    $query="INSERT INTO $table SET name='$name'"; 
  } 
  mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query); 
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);  
  exit;  
}  
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { //listing part: 
  $LIST=array(); 
  $query="SELECT * FROM $table";  
  $res=mysql_query($query); 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $LIST[]=$row; 
  include 'list.php'; 
} else { // form displaying part: 
  if ($id=intval($_GET['id'])) { 
    $query="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=$id";  
    $res=mysql_query($query); 
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) $row[$k]=htmlspecialchars($v); 
  } else { 
    $row['name']=''; 
    $row['id']=0; 
  } 
  include 'form.php'; 
}  
?>
```

And you will need 2 templates too, to hold your HTML

form.php

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$row['name']?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
<input type="submit"><br>
<a href="?">Return to the list</a>
</form>
```

list.php

```
<a href="?id=0">Add item</a>
<? foreach ($LIST as $row): ?>
<li><a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

use  `header("Location : ". $page);`   instead of `header("Location: $page");`

```
 if($_GET["Submit"])
          {
             $val=$_GET['event'];
             $remail=$_GET['email'];
            $rname = $_GET['ename'];
            $sqt=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET NAME='$rname',EMAIL='$remail' WHERE EID ='$val'");
            $page= "admin.php";
            header("Location : ". $page);
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, that is not going to work, isnce your edit.php will never reach its if statement, as you are not sending $_GET["submit"]. You need to do the following (send the submit variable by setting it to any value)

admin.php

```
 $event_id = $_SESSION['fedit'];
 if($_GET['edit'])
 {
   $url = "edit.php?event_id=". $event_id . "&submit=1";
   header("Location: $url");
 }
```

edit.php

```
if($_GET["Submit"])
{
   $val=$_GET['event'];
   $remail=$_GET['email'];
   $rname = $_GET['ename'];
   $sqt=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET NAME='$rname',EMAIL='$remail' WHERE EID ='$val'");
   header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

Comment: Changed the answer, check above

Comment: So, you can go from admin.php to edit.php, which saves the data to the database but doesnt redirect back?

Comment: Can you show me the full admin.php with the form. Just add it to your question above.

Comment: I got it done... I used this instead of header and i got it redirected... Thnx 4 the effort :) echo "<script>window.location.assign("admin.php")</script>";